# How can I create a Scrolling Dial for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

So I have all the images I need to create a Scroller Dial for the iPhone, but I don't know how I should animate them.

Basically I have a scroll dial that will essentially act as a UISlider but i'd like it to slow down as it spins.

How can I do something like that or where should I look to learn about these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UIScrollView. That will decelerate how you want and if you need it to form to a specific "tick", scroll the contentOffset of the scrollview to the proper tick.

Comment: Great so I got that going but how am i supposed to get some values out of that, I guess i need to grab what ever double value it's at

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073881/how-can-i-use-a-uiscrollview-to-change-values-just-like-a-uislider